# Windows Mobile - Notify/Restrict Application Install/UnInstall

Tags: c#, security, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am using .NET CF 2.0 with C#.

I need to create Policy enforcement application, which restricts backlisted application installation on windows mobile devices. How can I get notification for new application installation with an option to close the installation. I also need to get notification when someone uninstalls my application with an option to close the uninstall process.

Answer (score 0):

Policy enforcement on Windows Mobile can be tricky. I'd recommend not trying to do this yourself if possible.

I've had success with the [SPB Kiosk Engine](http://www.spb.com/pocketpc-software/kioskengine/) in the past and found it much simpler than locking down the device yourself. Previoulsy I've only been able to lock down specific devices with software from the device manufacturers.

To detect installation of other apps you would need to create an app/service to monitor installed applications.

There isn't a way to detect/prevent uninstallation without use of another proces to monitor this. Even then I'd expect it to be VERY tricky.

Comment: My application does not have any UI? How will I handle this?

Comment: @LetMeAsk That may or may not be an issue depending on the greater requirements for what else is also on the device and how much control you have over the device. Have you got any specifics with your situation what you've tried? Have you looked at the SPB Kiosk Engine?